# How to populate ComboBox with Strings from a list of objects?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a list of `Country` objects that have the instance variable `String countryName;`.
I can't figure out how to populate the `ComboBox` with a list of Country objects.

I tried doing it using a workaround by creating another list called

`ObservableList<String> listCountriesString = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

and looping over it and adding every instance variable `countryName` to a new list:

`private ObservableList<Country> listCountries = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

```
for (Country country : listCountries) {
    listCountriesString.add(country.getCountryName());
}
```

How can I use a ComboBox with my `Country` object, and displaying the country names only?

```
@FXML
ComboBox<Country> comboBoxCountry;
```

```
public class Country {
    private int countryId;
    private String countryName;
    private String createDate;
    private String lastUpdate;

    public Country(int countryId, String countryName, String createDate, String lastUpdate) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    ... getters and setters
```

Comment: please do some research before asking: read the api doc, work through some tutorial on how to use comboBox, apply what you learned to your context - when stuck, come back with a [mcve]

Comment: [The documentation for CombBox](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) explains how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward and it is part of the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) of course.

First you would need to create a `cellFactory` that takes care of setting the text of your `ComboBox` items.

```
Callback<ListView<Country>, ListCell<Country>> cellFactory = lv -> new ListCell<Country>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Country item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? "" : item.getCountryName());
    }

};
```

And then use it like this:

```java
comboBoxCountry.setButtonCell(cellFactory.call(null));
comboBoxCountry.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

Then you could add your `Countries` like this:

```java
comboBoxCountry.getItems().add(new Country("Germany"...));
```

Good luck!